# Having my SELECT with optgroup + optionsCaption with knockout seems to be ignored

Tags: knockout.js

I have a solution for using an optgroup with my SELECT html tag.

Here is the SO post: [Construct a knockout SELECT with optgroup based on observableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948619/construct-a-knockout-select-with-optgroup-based-on-observablearray)

[image]

Now I would like to allow an empty value in this SELECT. I try with optionsCaption:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: brands, optionsCaption: '  '">
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: $data}, foreach: $parent.vehicles">
    <!-- ko if: Brand == $parent -->
        <option data-bind="text: Type"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

But it doesn't work: no empty option.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also data-bind the visibility of the caption to $index < 1 if you only want to display the caption before the first group.

```
<select data-bind="foreach: brands">
    <option data-bind="visible: $index() < 1">Select vehicle</option>    
        <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: $data}, foreach: $parent.vehicles">
        <!-- ko if: Brand == $parent -->
        <option data-bind="text: Type"></option>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `optionsCaption` binding only in pair with `options` bindings. Since you don't use it you have to manually add empty option to the options list:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: brands">
     <option value=''>  </option>
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: $data}, foreach: $parent.vehicles">
    <!-- ko if: Brand == $parent -->
        <option data-bind="text: Type"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HPhmB/57/

Comment: I know it works in the jsfiddle but I try it in my proper application whith knockout validation and database backend and it doesn't work. I got a validation failed error when selecting this empty option. Any idea? I also try `<option value>   </option>`.

Comment: Maybe field you binded to the select is required therefore when you choose empty value validation is fail.

Comment: No it is not required. Fields required are marked in red automatically in my page. This one is not required for sure. I also changed the value directly in the database successfully (to test).

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with my db as backend. Maybe I can publish my test project somewhere to show you?

Comment: THey are all blank. this seems like an invalid solution.

Comment: To prevent multiple blank entries, place the option tag outside of the 'foreach: brands' loop.  To do this, use <!-- ko foreach: brands --> after the option tag.  Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder for proper use of the option.